# Dotnet Core - Obtaining shadow properties from a repository

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use the repository pattern. I use the methods listed in the interface.

Since, throughout my solution, I only have access to the repository and not context it makes sense to add this to the methods accessed from the repository interface. So I tried this:

This is the base repository. Of course, `IEntityBaseTENANTSRepository` has these method signatures listed in it, but here you see where I try and obtain a shadow property.

```
public class EntityBaseTENANTSRepository<T> : IEntityBaseTENANTSRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
    private readonly TENANTSContext _context;   

    public EntityBaseTENANTSRepository(TENANTSContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   ...

    // Shadow properties
    public DateTime GetSPCreatedOn()
    {
        return (DateTime) _context.Entry(typeof(T)).Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue;
    } 
}
```

For each of the entities I have a Repository that inherits from the above -

```
public class AccountTENANTSRepository : EntityBaseTENANTSRepository<Account>, IAccountTENANTSRepository
{
    private readonly TENANTSContext _context;

    public AccountTENANTSRepository(TENANTSContext context) : base(context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
}
```

I can access this via the individual entity repositories that derive from the base entity where the methods are -

```
var test = _tenantTENANTSRepository.GetSPCreatedOn();
```

This yields the error:

> The entity type 'RuntimeType' was not found. Ensure that the entity
> type has been added to the model.

Because I don't have access to `DbContext` throughout my solution but I do the repository I want to use methods in my base repository. Seems elegant so that anywhere I want to access the shadow property I can access that method. What am I doing wrong and how do I get the shadow property out of the database using this type of access?

Comment: If you expose the FK properties in your model, then you won't have shadow properties at all. As soon as you need them, just put them in the model as first class properties.

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: The error message doesn't indicate anything about any property, shadow or not.  What is the `RuntimeType` entity, and why is it not found?

Comment: Sometimes the hardest thing is to understand what the problem really is.. in this case I needed to pass the entity and use that.. eg public int GetSPCreatedById(T entity)
        {
            return (int) _context.Entry(entity).Property("CreatedById").CurrentValue;
        }

Comment: @atiyar is right, your title suggests shadow properties, but the error has nothing to do with them. However to obtain the _key_ field values, make them properties in your model, that way there is no hidden shadow property, the properties will be regular members on your model. Show us a simple example of your model class, and the navigation configuration, That I can post an answer to

Comment: Thanks Chris and yes @atiyar was right.. Once he pointed out that it wasnt even recognising the entity it was apparent I wasnit using an entity but Typeof(T). I needed the actual entity instead.. see my entry above where i changed it.. It now works.